# Antonym for jinx

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, antonyms

"Jinx" has a negative connotation for an action.

What's the opposite, an action that had a positive consequence under the superstition?

Like "lucky charm", but that doesn't really work.

I'm looking for a verb, similar to how you would say "The return to office date got pushed back. I shouldn't have said I was looking forward to it, I [jinxed] it.".

"Woohoo! The return to office date got pushed back, when I said it wasn't going to happen I [somehow positively influenced] it."

Comment: Are you looking for something that works the opposite of  this then? — *“I'm beginning to think that damned team is a **jinx**... It's been a bad-luck team from the beginning.”*

Comment: Why doesn't *lucky charm* work? Are you looking for a noun or a verb? Can you supply a sentence with a blank space where the word you want would be inserted?

Comment: @JasonBassford Thanks, I added some example sentences. Yes, I'm looking for a verb.

Comment: Are you thinking *blessed* or *beknighted*?

Comment: Does this have to 21st century casual language? The 19th Century sometimes used *to fluke* to mean randomly achieving something as a lucky break. *Bennett..tried for a cannon, but fluked the white, and..ran out the winner by 90 points.* and  *He wanted to fluke a last success.* and  *Even if he managed to fluke home in this trial.*

Comment: @tchrist I'd still use fluke, personally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After clarification of the question, what's being looked for is a verb that's the antonym of *jinx*, and used in a superstitious context.

I believe that [**invoke**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/evoke) satisfies those criteria:

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **2** : to call forth by [incantation](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incantation) : [CONJURE](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conjure)
>
> // Nietzsche is so complex that he can be *invoked* in support of many outlooks, some of them brutal or nihilistic.
> — Thomas Nagel, *New Republic*, 14 Jan. 2002
>
> // There are some people who commit murder as a way of *invoking* the death penalty. Capital punishment can sometimes, then, be equivalent to suicide.
> — George Freeman Solomon, People, 17 Jan. 1977

Used in the example sentence in the question, and paraphrasing it slightly so that it makes sense with the word, it would look like this:

> ""Woohoo! The return to office date got pushed back, when I said it wasn't going to happen I *invoked* that result."

---

A similar word is [*evoke*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/evoke), but I personally feel it doesn't have quite as active a sense of summoning something real as does *invoke*, and instead is more commonly associated with recollection.

[Google Books NGram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=26&smoothing=3&content=invoke%20evil%20spirits%2Cevoke%20evil%20spirits&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinvoke%20evil%20spirits%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cevoke%20evil%20spirits%3B%2Cc0) also indicates that *invoke evil spirits* is about three times as common as *evoke evil spirits*:

[image: invoke versus evoke evil spirits]

Comment: Nice, it doesn't sound as colloquial as jinx but has it's own flavor

Answer (score 5):

Maybe "blessing" could work!

According to Oxford's English Dictionary, a blessing is "a beneficial thing for which one is grateful; something that brings well-being."

*Edit, after your clarification:*
I’ve often heard people use the word “called” in these situations. Something happened that I said would happen? I called it!

> “Woohoo! The return to office date got pushed back, when I said it wasn’t going to happen I called it.”

Although it isn’t formal English, it’s a pretty common phrase. To say you “called it” implies that you predicted it would happen.